# How to make angular show only the data that is available

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook

In my view I want to show the image of the user. I have users that log in in my app through facebook and users that log in with email and pass. When the user logs in from Facebook I take the picture from their Facebook and display it on the view, if they log in with email I take their picture that I have in the database. How can I make angularjs take the picture that i available to it. Can I do smth like this

```
<img ng-src="{{user.picture}}" ng-src="{{pic[1]}}">
```

Put both images and if the user.picture is available it will show it, otherwise show pic[1].

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use '||' (or) in your view like this:

`<img ng-src="{{user.picture || pic[1]}}" />`

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
<img ng-src="{{user.picture}}" ng-if="user.picture">
<img ng-src="{{pic[1]}}" ng-if="!user.picture">
```

In this way, if `user.picture` is not undefined, it will be shown. Otherwise it shows the other one

Comment: Thanks but the image layout for the undefined image was still there

Answer (score 1):

A rough solution, simply use two images, hide them based on the value of `user.picture`

```
<img ng-src="{{user.picture}}" ng-hide='!user.picture'>
<img  ng-src="{{pic[1]}}" ng-hide='user.picture'>
```

---

**Solution 2:**

Another option would be to set just one image with src, which conditionally changes inside the controller.

for ex:

```
<img ng-src="{{finalPic}}" />
```

And in controllerJs, after when you already get your images, put:

```
$scope.finalPic=$scope.user.picture?$scope.user.picture:$scope.pic[1];
```

Comment: Thanks but the image layout for the undefined image was still there